# Excel 2016 - Extract the name that contains all items in a list

Tags: excel

Given a list like:

```
Item    Name
Item1   Name1
Item1   Name1
Item1   Name1
Item1   Name1
item2   Name2
Item1   Name2
Item1   Name2
Item1   Name2
Item1   Name2
Item1   Name3
Item1   Name3
Item1   Name3
Item1   Name3
Item1   Name4
Item1   Name5
item2   Name6
Item1   Name7
```

I want to extract the name where it has all of the items. See Name2 has both Item1 and Item2. All other Names have either Item1 or Item2 but not both. There are duplicates because there are other columns not shown. Note that there could be more than 2 items. Ultimately, this list will end up being pivoted with filters/slicers so that when someone selects multiple items there will be a way for them to see only the name(s) that have all of the items selected. Suggestions using formulas or PIVOT tables or a combination are good.

Result would look something like:

```
Item    Name
Item2   Name2
Item1   Name2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a few items to your list for testing.

```
   Item3    Name2
   Item3    Name4
   Item3    Name6
```

The first step is to create a pivot table and add a slicer on Item as below.

[image: Output Summary]

Because of the slicer, the columns and rows shown in the pivot table need to be counted.  The formula in for counting columns in C12 is `=COUNTA(C2:F2)-1`.  This way when the slicer reduces the number of columns, the result is the number of items.

Similarly, count the rows in C13 using `=COUNTA(B3:B10)-1`.

Then in cell A3 enter `=IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET(C3,0,0,1,$C$12),"")=0,B3,"")`. This formula returns the name if all items are not blank.  Copy this formula down the column.

Next in C14 enter `=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,OFFSET(Pivot!A3,0,0,C13,1))`.  This lists all of the names with all items delimited by a ", ".  The `OFFSET` is there to keep from list Grand Total when there are less than 7 names because of the slicer.

Finally, the formula for H2:H4 is `=IF(ROW()-1<=$C$12,INDEX($C$2:$E$2,ROW()-1),"")`.  And in I2 is `=IF(H2="","",$C$14)`.  This will then need to be copied to I3:I4.

Below is an example showing the results for Items 2&3.

[image: Items 2&3]